# Getting ip address from user name in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp, remoting

I am working on a windows service. I need to transfer files over network using TCP/IP. Now the problem is I have only network username to connect. Is there any way I can find the ip address of a user using its network username.

Comment: Users have no ip addresses. Machines have.

Comment: Users can be logged into multiple machines and may not have a single associated IP address. This is not going to be possible.

Comment: By user network name i mean the machine name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string name = "somename";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(name);

foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
{
   Console.WriteLine(theaddress.ToString());
}
```